# Prototype.js Issue

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Protype.js is throwing a peculiar error :

`typeerror value does not implement interface node`

And it showsthis line in the fire bug console as the culprit behind :

`var query= document.evaluate(expression, $(parentElement) || document,
 null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);`

Any body has any idea what's going wrong in here?

Comment: In which browser (version)? What values do `expression` and `parentElement` have? How does your DOM (markup) look like? Does Prototype or `document.evaluate` throw that error?

Comment: In Mozilla 21.0, 

value of `expression` :".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' e ')]"

Value of `parentElement`  : `div` and then it conatins a whole lot of DOM mark up like  `ByTags`, `ByID` etc

This is strange, i loaded the page again and now i get errors for those 2 attributes like : `ReferenceError: expression is not defined` and `ReferenceError: parentElement is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error references `document.getElementsByClassName()` which has technically been deprecated in favor of `$$()`

So instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('MyClass')` use `$$('.MyClass')`

Or if you want to keep the scope of the selection down to one element's children

```
$('myElementId').select('.MyClass');
```

Will select all of the elements with `MyClass` class that are children of the element identified by id `myElementId`

Comment: Thanks, i will check this one out and get back to you .